# How to expose Docker-Registry behind Apache httpd?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-registry, apache2.4

I'm running a private docker-registry v2 with the following **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/server-cert.pem
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/server-key.pem
    REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
  volumes:
    - /data/docker-registry:/var/lib/registry
    - /certs/docker-registry:/certs
    - /auth/docker-registry:/auth
```

and I'm able to do the login locally (SSH, Jenkins,...) at **http://localhost:5000**.

Now I would like to expose this registry with Apache httpd.
I'm running the following version of httpd on CentOS 7:

```
[root@dev-machine conf.d]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59
```

This is my **vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dev-machine.com
    ServerAlias www.dev-machine.com

    ErrorLog logs/dev-machine.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dev-machine.com-access_log common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /certs/docker-registry/server-cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /certs/docker-registry/server-key.pem

    Header set Host "dev-machine.com"
    Header set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass           /registry       http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse    /registry       http://127.0.0.1:5000/

    <Location /registry>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        AuthName "Registry Authentication"
        AuthType basic
        AuthUserFile "/auth/htpasswd"
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to login on the registry I get the following error:

```
izio@1z10:~$ docker login https://dev-machine.com/registry
Username: user
Password: 
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://dev-machine/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

It seems like redirecting to /v2 instead of using the assigned url in vhosts. What is missing or wrong with this configuration?

Comment: maybe its easy to use nginx instead of apache for this

Comment: wouldn'it create problems since right now it's all behind Apache, and in addition the only ports I can use are 80 and 443?

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan It is easy in apache, too. Note also, apache with a [multi-threaded mpm](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-mpms-explained/) performs very well (I don't have benchmarks but I suspect it can be better than nginx).

Comment: Is this configuration still working? I've tried to do the same configuration and, no matter what I do, I am unable to use an alias other than /v2.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to differentiate read users, from push users. It's unclear how to do it.

Comment: Also maybe relevant to ServerFault

Comment: Also it would be useful to edit the title to mention that you want a "sub directory" and not a "traditional" Docker registry on the base directory. So this question would be even more clear and more unique compared to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update your `httpd.conf` like this:

```
ProxyPass           /registry       http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
ProxyPassReverse    /registry       http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
```

Note the "/v2"